# Biased dependent variable on logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, sas

I am working on a logistic regression with a biased dependent variable, (only 22 observations for 0 but 222 observations for 1) on SAS program. In such case, what can I do to transform the dependent variable into a less biased case?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "bias" about a dependent variable like that, and there is nothing wrong with performing logistic regression on it. It will limit the number of predictors you can include (there are rules of thumb of how many predictors per event are allowed, and in this case, the event is the smaller number, i.e., 22), but that is just an unavoidable quality of the data.